# Error: "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception

I want to make any input by the user print out in file FCITrecurse.in, and the output print out in file FCITrecurse.out.

So, this is my code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    int numOfCommands;
    String command;

    // make input file
    File inputFile = new File("FCITrecurse.in");
    if (!inputFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Input file, " + inputFile + ", does not exist.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    // make output file
    File outputFile = new File("FCITrecurse.out");

    // Make Scanner for input and Printwriter for output
    Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);

    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outputFile);

    // Scan the # of commands from the file (the int on the first line of input file)
    numOfCommands = input.nextInt();


    // Now do a for loop over the number of commands
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfCommands; i++) {
        // Scan the next command from the input file
        command = input.next();

        // Now check which command was read, and call the appropriate methods

        // Command: FCITmultiply
        if (command.equals("FCITmultiply") == true) {
            // We call the WRAPPER method countDown()
            FCITmultiply(input, output);
        } // Command: FCITflip
        else if (command.equals("FCITflip") == true) {
            // We call the WRAPPER method FCITflip()
            FCITflip(input, output);
        } // Command: FCITshape
        else if (command.equals("FCITshape") == true) {
            // We call the WRAPPER method FCITshape()
            FCITshape(input, output);
        } // Command: FCITgame
        else if (command.equals("FCITgame") == true) {
            // We call the WRAPPER method FCITgame()
            FCITgame(input, output);
        } // WRONG CHOICE
        else {
            ; // do nothing
        }
    }

    // Close input and output
    input.close();
    output.close();

}
```

and this is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)enter code here
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at p.P.main(P.java:116)
```

this is line 116:

```
// Scan the # of commands from the file (the int on the first line of input file)
    int numOfCommands = input.nextInt();
```

it's originally don't accept input? any input `int` or `string`.

what is my problem here?

If i change my code like this it will work but it will not save the input in an external input file

```
    // Make Scanner for input and Printwriter for output
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: You can check with hasNextInt() if there is actually an int on the input, cuz that is was causing the exception. Thereby are you sure the file contains integers, otherwise you can use nextLine() or simply next()

Comment: it's originally don't accept input? any input int or string.

Comment: input.nextInt only accepts Integer, if you enter some other element it will throw an exception.

Comment: it didn't accepting integer or anything else. i just run the program and it show me this error.

Comment: @Montaldo has your answer.  You seem to be blowing past the end of the Scanner.  The exception you have seems to indicate that there are no more elements left to return.  Either check before you read the next int, or catch the exception and use that to indicate EOF.

Comment: how can i do that? sorry but i just started learn java in 3 weeks ago. I found this exercise in a website that makes me learn writing input and output in an external file.

Comment: See @Montaldo's first comment, put that line of code in an if (input.hasNextInt()) block.

Comment: @EricHydrick didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If the code you posted is accurate, you have too many copies of the for loop over commands.  You are running your loop body n<sup>2</sup> times instead of n times.

Have you tested the program in the case your input file has 0 or 1 command in it?

Do your wrapper methods use the input scanner in some way that advances it too far?

Comment: I tested it if (Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in); and it works very well. but the external input file has nothing in it unlike the output file